# How to Dispose() after every HTTP request using Scoped Service in OnModelCreating()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a multi-tenant app and for every `HTTP Request` it should validate the `Headers` for the property `AccountId`.

**Global query filters** are a good way to isolate tenants mentioned in [.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) but it doesn't list how you can dispose state after each request.

Here is an example:

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**
Has a global query filter for `Account` entity using `AccountId` injected by the `FooHeaderService`

```cs
private readonly IFooHeader _fooHeaders;

public ApplicationDbContext(IFooHeader fooHeaders) : base(options)
{
    this._fooHeaders = fooHeaders;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating() {
    FooHeaders foo = this._fooHeaders.GetFooHeaders().AccountId;

    // or using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure
    FooHeaders foo = this.Database.GetService<IFooHeaders>();
    Guid fooId = foo.AccountId;     // MUST DISPOSE BETWEEN REQUESTS!

    // Global Query Filter
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasQueryFilter(filter => filter.AccountId = fooId)
}
```

**FooHeaderService**
Gets the `Headers` for `AccountId`

```cs
public class FooHeaderService : IFooHeaders
{
    private readonly FooHeaders _headers;

    public FooHeaderService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _headers.AccountId = contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request
             .Headers["accountId"].ToString();
    }

    public FooHeaders GetFooHeaders() => _headers;
}
```

**Startup.cs**
Register `FooHeaderService` as `ScopedService`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IFooHeader, FooHeaderService>();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

**Issue**

Without properly disposing, the variable `fooId = AccountId` inside `OnModelCreating()` persists between `HTTP Requests` (very dangerous stuff!).

**How do you dependency inject `FooHeaderService` into `OnModelCreating()` and dispose state for each `HTTP Request` cycle?**

Comment: Your registering the context and the service as scoped, so you should get new instances per request. So everything above should work properly. Are you sure that's what your code looks like? Also if you need disposal of the service type, implement IDisposable so that the instances are disposed after their scope ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the sample here:
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Querying/QueryFilters/BloggingContext.cs

OnModelCreating only runs once, so you can't resolve a particular AccountId there.  Instead pass a service into your DbContext constructor that allows you to get to the AccountId.  You actually already have done that, you're just not using it in OnModelCreating.

So this should be

```
public ApplicationDbContext(IFooHeader fooHeaders) : base(options)
{
    this._fooHeaders = fooHeaders;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating() {

    // Global Query Filter
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasQueryFilter(filter => filter.AccountId = this._fooHeaders.AccountId)
}
```

That way every Request gets a new DbContexts (since it's scoped), and every DbContext has different IFooHeaders to plug into the global query filter.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [HttpResponse.RegisterForDisposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.registerfordispose?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method:

```cs
HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDisposal(fooId);
```